# ExpressJS receiving invalid JSON format

Tags: node.js, express

Below is the invalid JSON format that my expressJS is receiving. Is there any way to fix it on the expressjs end?

```
{ '{"key": "value"}': '' }
```

I have tried to pass these but it didn't make any difference

```html
// parse application/json
app.use(express.json());

app.use(
  express.urlencoded({
    extended: true,
    strict: false,
  })
);
```

Incoming header

```
headers: {
host: 'x.x.x.x',
accept: '*/*',
'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate',
'accept-language': 'en',
'user-agent': 'MetaTrader 5 Terminal/5.2560 (Windows NT 10.0; x64; Hyper-V)',
connection: 'keep-alive',
'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
'content-length': '16'
```

},

Comment: Have you tried with body parser ? https://www.npmjs.com/package/body-parser

Comment: Yes I have, anything I need to look into?

Comment: Its looks like not body-parser issue. Check your your route code from there these invalid value are send.

Comment: Do you want a valid json string or what is your goal ? Where does your invalid jsons tring come from ? Pleas clearify your question more

Comment: Yes, I want valid format. I should be getting {"key": "value"}

Comment: It's coming from a software called meta trader. I'm Posting the same payload to a third-party endpoint and it formatted correctly.

Answer (score 0):

If there's no way to have that meta-trader send data in a valid JSON format, the only way I see is to:

- identify the first-key of what was sent by meta-trader
- Parse the JSON from the key-string

  contentFromMetaTrader = { '{"key": "value"}': '' }

  JSON.parse(Object.entries(contentFromMetaTrader)[0][0])

Output of line-2 will be {key: value} that you are looking for.

Note that, the above is only a path-solution to live with what you have. Not the ideal-world-scenario.